# Reordering logic of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reorder elements. Some elements have a class `.image_container` and some don't. I want to get all the elements that have said class to render at the top of the container and the ones that don't to render at the end.

The logic I am using seems to be slightly off but I simply cannot figure out where/what. I am hoping a second pair of eyes will help! Thank you!

Below is my code:

```js
$('.teaser').each(function() {
if ($(this).find('figure.image_container').length !== 0) {
    if ($(this).prev().find('figure.image_container').length == 0) {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
    }
   } else if ($(this).find('figure.image_container').length == 0) {
      if ($(this).next().find('figure.image_container').length !== 0) {
        $(this).next().insertBefore($(this));
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't you make two arrays? One for elements with the class and one for elements without the class? Then in your loop check if it contains the class, if it does add it to the array of elements with the class, if not add it to the other array. Then in the end you can merge both arrays and render that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tsr = $(".teaser");
var arr = [];
var nodesWithClass = $(".teaser figure.image_container");
nodesWithClass.each(function() {
    arr.push(this);
});
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].parentNode.removeChild(arr[i]);
    tsr.prepend($(arr[i]));
}
```